# How to set UISlider's MinimumTrackImage so that it won't strech?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby, uislider, rubymotion

Ever since I've updated my XCode, the `MinimumTrackImage` on my UISlider is now stretching, when before it was clipping like I wanted it to. The `MaximumTrackImage`'s behavior didn't change.

**How can I get the `MinimumTrackImage` to not stretch?** Note that I use rubymotion, but a solution using obj-c is also acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing here (you are allowed to guess on StackOverflow as long as you're honest about it)...  There is a new iOS6 feature for images and perhaps that is getting in your way here.  You can set the `resizingMode` and `capInsets` for an image.  Try this:

```
// Objective-C
UIImage *newImage = [oldImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];

# RubyMotion
newImage = oldImage.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero, resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile)
```

If you need to adjust the insets as well, replace `UIEdgeInsetsZero` with `UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)` where `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` are `floats`.  In RubyMotion, I believe you can just use `[top, left, bottom, right]`.

Info came from here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I now see that Apple says not to call `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` with `UIImageResizingModeTile` but to just call `resizableImageWithCapInsets` instead.  That's kind of crazy to have a parameter with just 2 possible values, one of which you shouldn't use!!!

Comment: I think the real answer to your problem is to make sure the image you are providing is already the exact dimensions you need so that no clipping or resizing is needed.

Comment: You're really saving me from major headaches! Thanks a lot, using `resizableImageWithCapInsets` did the trick. I already had the image at the exact size, so just adding `newImage = oldImage.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero, resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile)` did the trick

Comment: FYI, I wrote an article on the subject, available here: http://marcgg.com/2012/10/22/custom-slider-ios-rubymotion/